# batch file, string manuplutation with dir command

Tags: batch-file

Trying to get this to work.

Getting this line from dir:    `3 File(s)  7,332,731,128 bytes` and trying to just get the number of files to use for addition.

```
@Echo ON

dir %1 /a:h | find "File(s)" > hidden.txt
dir %1 | find "File(s)" > reg.txt

set /p hidden=<hidden.txt
echo %hidden%
IF /I "%hidden%"=="File Not Found" (
    Set hidden = 0
    ) Else (
Set hidden=%hidden~-29%)

echo %hidden%
Set /p reg=<reg.txt
IF /I "%hidden%"=="File Not Found" (
    set reg = 0
    ) ELSE (
    Set reg=%reg~-29%)
set /a total = %reg% + %hidden%

Echo The total number of files in the %1 directory is: %total%. This includes hidden files.
Echo.
Echo The total number of non-hidden files in the %1 directory is: %reg%.
Echo.
Echo The total number of hidden files in the %1 directory is: %hidden%
```

Comment: You can use a `FOR /F` command to either read the output file you created or parse the output of the `DIR` and `FIND` commands. By default the output will be split by the first space.  So you can assign the `FOR` variable to an environmental variable to use later in your script.

Comment: A better option would be to use the `/C` option of the `FIND` command to count the number of files. `dir "%1"/a:h-d /b|find /c /v ""`

Answer (score 1):

you don't need temp files which only will slow down your script:

if you want to count the hidden files try this

```
@echo off
set counter=0
for /f %%# in ('dir /a:h-d "%~1"') do (
  set /a counter=counter+1
)
echo hidden files=%counter%
```

to count all files

```
@echo off
set counter=0
for /f %%# in ('dir /a:-d "%~1"') do (
  set /a counter=counter+1
)
echo all files=%counter%
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just another `For` loop option:

```bat
@For /F %%A In ('Dir/AH-D-L "%~1" 2^>Nul') Do @If Not "%%A"=="0" Set "fileCount=%%A"
@Echo %fileCount%
@Pause
```

*Remove `-L`, if you wish not to exclude junction points from your file count.*

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same result with just two FOR loops. Using sentences between single quotes inside the parentheses we can execute commands and store results.

I've left the same Result Text just to let you compare and see if this is what you're looking for:

**CODE**:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f %%A in ('dir "%~1" /a-h-d /b ^| find /V /C ""') do set "visCount=%%A"
for /f %%A in ('dir "%~1" /ah-d /b ^| find /V /C ""') do set "hidCount=%%A"

set /a totalCount = visCount + hidCount

echo.
echo The total number of files in the %1 directory is: %totalCount%. This includes hidden files.
echo.
echo The total number of non-hidden files in the %1 directory is: %visCount%.
echo.
echo The total number of hidden files in the %1 directory is: %hidCount%
```

With /B parameter of DIR command I only get one line per file and no more text, and with /A I can select Hidden or not files and no directories.

Then SET /A command let us use arithmetics operations.